# Build a project programmatically into an assembly and add references

Tags: c#, asp.net, roslyn, codedom

I would like to build a project ( in code ) into an assembly.

The reason why i want to do this is because i want to use the

'Services.AddApplicationParts( -Here i insert external assembly containing mvc controller along with entity framework context and so on-)'

in ASP.NET CORE ( using the full framework ) to load an external class library.

I have been trying to do just that for some time but various problems popup in regards to references that the project which i am trying to compile programmatically into an assembly, has.

I will post some code as a starting point.Please do come up as another starting point if you prefer.

```
 MSBuildWorkspace workspace = MSBuildWorkspace.Create(new Dictionary<string, string> { { "CheckForSystemRuntimeDependency", "true" } });


            Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Solution solution = workspace.OpenSolutionAsync(@"E:\consoleVic\ConsoleTryCompile\ConsoleTryCompile.sln").Result;

            Project pr = solution.Projects.First(x => x.Name == "WebClassLibrary"); 

            // pr has no documents.
```

the 'pr' has no documents and no references when i check its public 'get' properties.

Comment: I'm not really sure what you're trying to do here.  Are you simply trying to load a solution into a new workspace, or wanting to load a solution in it's existing workspace?  Are you trying to create solutions/projects to dynamically create assemblies, or simply dynamically compile them with existing solutions/projects.  In the case of simply loading a solution/projects, we'd need a lot more info to go on to tell you why the project has no documents, other than that's the way it was created and you need to add the documents you want.

Comment: well it is obvious that i want to compile a project inside a visual studio solution into an assembly to be latter loaded by asp.net core.I wrote that in the description

Comment: yes, but created from scratch, or already existing?  If you have a project that has no documents in it, why?  Do you need help adding documents to it, or figuring out why it has no documents?